# What is the name of the part of the parenthesized expression of a for-loop that terminates the loop?

Tags: for-loop, terminology

I'm trying to answer the following question:

> What is the name of the part of a for-loop that terminates the loop?

The parenthesis is the `()`, but I don't get the rest of the question. If I had a loop like:

```
// enter code here

int k = 0;
for (int j=0;j<=10;j++)
{
  k++
}
```

what is the name of the `j<=10` sub-expression?

Comment: "Loop terminator" or "Loop exit condition"?

Comment: Okay nvm I found it 

The break statement
If break is encountered inside a loop the loop terminates regardless of the status of the control statement. Code execution continues with the first line of code following the loop structure.

Answer (score 4):

> What is the name of the part of the parenthesis...of a for-loop that terminates the loop?

In your example, `j<=10` is the part of the overall loop expression that defines the [exit condition](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-construct-a-basic-for-loop-in-the-c-languag.html) for the loop. Some sources describe this part of the loop expression as the [continue or end condition](http://www.codingunit.com/c-tutorial-for-loop-while-loop-break-and-continue). This sub-expression can probably be described in other ways, too, but *exit condition* is pretty unambiguous and clearly communicates its purpose and intent. Whenever the exit condition evaluates as true, the loop will exit.

You can, of course, also place additional loop controls inside the body of the loop such as *break* or *continue*. However, these flow-control keywords aren't part of the definition of the loop itself, and are thus outside the scope of your original question.

Answer (score 2):

You might call it the for loop's "condition" as it's called at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for for example.

```
for ([initialization]; [condition]; [final-expression])
   statement
```

Comment: Hm so the terminator condition here is when j reaches ten?

Comment: Or if I had a if (k==5) break; then would that be the termination condition?

Comment: I changed my answer to just call it the loop's "condition", because it's the condition in which it *continues*, not terminates. In your example, the "condition" is `j<=10`.

Answer (score -3):

The answer is "the break statement".

Comment: Incorrect. `break` can be used inside the loop to terminate the loop prematurely irrespective of the loop's termination condition. The `break` statement does not go in the loop header, which is (I think) what this question is about.